# How to reuse the existing store to populate the combobox in Extjs?

Tags: extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have a "Ext.grid.Panel" , which is populated using the store.
Combobox need to be populated with the values from the "Ext.grid.panel" 1st one column.

Ex: Sample UI.

```
 _______
|Button |
 -------
 -----------------------------
  emp name |  emp no
 -----------------------------
  xxx          ABC
  yyy          XYZ
 ----------------------------
```

Question :
if the user clicks the above button i need to show popup with form with combobox as form field. it needs to be populated with the "emp name" from the 
above grid. i am using the store to populate the grid. how to use the same store for populating the combobox ?

Answer (score 0):

If you create the store outside the initialization of the grid panel, you can use it as many places as you would like - I'm a little out of practice, but something like this in the init function of a view/panel/container (definitely an error or two since this is just off memory from ext a year ago) and you might need to double check this all in the docs:

```
init: function () {
    var store = Ext.create('App.store.Employees').load();

    var contextMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
        items: {xtype: 'form', items: [
            {xtype: 'combo', store: store}
        ]
    });

    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columns [....]
    });

    Ext.applyIf(this, {
        items: [
            {xtype: 'button', itemId: 'MyButton'},
            grid
        ]
    });

    this.callParent(arguments);

    var button = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#MyButton')[0]
    button.getEl().on('contextmenu', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        contextMenu.show(button.getEl());
    });
}
```